# Mac Sonoma - file not showing default application icon

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, icon, sonoma

I have switch to mac and trying to make files look different based on their type. I have .wav files with default application set to default 'Music' app but it doesn't show Music app icon in file. See the picture below.

[image]

how do I set icon for all .wav file to icon of Music app?.

Thanks

Comment: My Mac (macOS 14.2.1) shows exactly the same as yours. I think that is the default. But you still may want to change it!

Comment: It bit difficult to differentiate when you have lots of file and they all have white and grey icons. It would be nice to have icon same as assigned application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're showing the icon preview, not the icon. That makes sense for image files, where it can show a thumbnail, but not really for audio, where all it can display is a generic 'music' symbol.

You can set this as a global default, for all folders without an existing setting, or on a folder by folder basis.
In Finder, View Menu > Show View Options, or  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>

[image]
<sub>Icons shown here are from iTunes rather than Music, but newer OSes will use Music.</sub>

Comment: Thanks it fixed it. Once complain now is picture files have lots its preview. Window had a plus point here I think. Files where showing application icon and picture shows preview.

Comment: tbh, I never keep photos & sound files in the same folders, nor do I ever use icon view, so I can't say it's ever bothered me.